# Is it possible to forward properties?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

Is it possible to forward a property?

Let's say I have a proxy class that has a member which has in turns a property called `string`.

I want my proxy class to have the same property also named `string`. From there, I would like that whenever I call the getter/setter on the proxy, it set/get value on its class member.

the closest I have come to it is to implement `-forwardingTargetForSelector` and switch the target when needed but it's not clean nor pratical (it gives warning and you cannot use the dot-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the properties as `@dynamic` and implement these two methods to handle the forwarding - [`methodSignatureForSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-methodSignatureForSelector_) and [`forwardInvocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-forwardInvocation_). Implementation will be something has described below –

```
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ( alpha && [alpha respondsToSelector:aSelector] ) {
        return [alpha methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    } else {
        return [super methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    }
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    if ( alpha && [alpha respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]] ) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:alpha];
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much what I wrote in the question... I know this exist. Just feel it's not "pretty". Actually the @dynamic bit is something I forgot to mention which removes all warning.

Thank you for the reminder!